# Options in the jquery-ui tooltip function does not having any affect on tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am trying to add a [jQuery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#tracking) tooltip to my rails application.

By following the given example, I configured my javascript. I am trying to use below mentioned two options. But none seems working.

```
$(document).tooltip({
    track: true,
    position: { 
      my: "center", 
      at: "center bottom" 
    }
  });
```

I got a tooltip but it was very simple tooltip with a simple black background and the options i specified was not making any affect on tooltip.

Comment: try using a class selector instead of document

Comment: I have tried accessing using class and also id of the element and tooltip is coming , but the problem here is, options specified in the tooltip function is not at all affecting the tooltip, so i could not able position my tooltip and i could not able to enable track option to my tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a jsfiddle or codepen of this issue? Would be happy to try to help you. This should work if your item has a tooltip class:

```
$(".tooltip").tooltip({
    track: true,
    position: { 
      my: "center", 
      at: "center bottom" 
    }
});
```

Make sure also that the title attribute is set on the tooltip item or you set content: "" in your .tooltip({}); options.